# Simple HTML form into SQL DB using PHP, getting hammered by bots

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, .htaccess

I have a very simple HTML form which is for pre-registering for my car show. Unfortunately it has attracted the attention of spammers because there's an "address" field which they use to inject their spam URLs into.

I've added javascript form validation which says if the address field contains any slashes (like "http://") then it pops up a box telling spammers to go away.

I've added htaccess that I thought was supposed to stop users from being able to hit the PHP file which is used to submit the form into the DB without coming from my domain first.

I had recaptcha, but they were able to get around that as well so I removed it since it wasn't effective.

I know one flaw is that I can browse directly to my PHP file and it will insert a blank row into the database - how can I prevent this as well?

Does anyone have a good site or steps to take to stop these bots from hitting my form?

Comment: In addition to what the others have said you should never rely on javascript form validation, also validate on the server side level

Answer (score 2):

ReCaptcha, if well configured, should have solved your problem. There's no easy way to "go around that".

> I've added htaccess that I thought was supposed to stop users from
>   being able to hit the PHP file which is used to submit the form into
>   the DB without coming from my domain first.

That's probably your problem. The bots are problem just calling the registration page with the right parameters. One way to get around it would be to display a hidden input field on your form, populate it with some random value, and check that you get the same value when the form is submitted.

But again ReCaptcha should work... if it doesn't you should ask a specific question about that.

Comment: ReCaptcha can be found here: https://www.google.com/recaptcha and a simple form validation with: $sample=  filter_var($_POST['sample'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); will remove dangerous data.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, validate the data that are send from the Form, check them if are valid, not empty. etc. If you are using a framework those have validation classes(use it), else create some,

second put back the [captcha](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/php-captcha-class-simple-php-captcha-example/) and don't send any data to the server if this isn't valid